# Update DB with ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I use ADO.NET EF 4.0. First I get object from DB and detach this object, sent by web service on client side.

web service:

```
    private static Project GetObjects(int id)
    {
        var connSetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectEntities"];
        var conn = new EntityConnection(connSetting.ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        using(var contex= new ProjectEntities(conn))
        {
            var project = (from p in contex.Projects
                           where p.ProjectId == id
                           select p).FirstOrDefault();

            contex.Detach(project);

            return project;
        }
    }
```

on client side, is this object edited a sent back to web service, on web service side I need update with this object DB.

Now I use this:

```
    private static void UpdateObject(Project obj)
    {
        var connSetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectEntities"];
        var conn = new EntityConnection(connSetting.ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        using (var contex = new ProjectEntities(conn))
        {
            var entity = (Project)contex.GetObjectByKey(obj.EntityKey);
            contex.ApplyCurrentValues(entity.EntityKey.EntitySetName, obj);
            contex.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

This method for update is ok? Because first I must get object from object contex and then I can update.

What you suggest. Thank you for your help and advice

Comment: Not sure why you are manually opening the connection, it seems like unnecessary work when you just pass the `Context` the `ConnectionString` and allow it to open and close the database connection as it needs it.  (Not exactly what you were looking for, but if there is some other reason for this, then maybe I would learn something).

Answer (score 1):

We do it the following way:
    context.TableName.Attach(object);
    context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(object, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
    context.SaveChanges();

EntityState.Modified can be changed to EntityState.Added to add a new item or Deleted to delete an existing item.